# Why doesn't my route load on node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Why doesn't my Express node.js app doesn't load when I navigate to /searching? I am on the correct port so I am puzzled why doesn't it load; it gives a 404 error message. I highlighted the part which is problematic below.

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
 app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 app.use('/', index);
 app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

 app.get('/', function(req, res) {res.render('index')});
 **app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
 res.send("WHEEE");
 });**

  // error handler
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 // set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

 // render the error page
 res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');
 });

 module.exports = app;
 app.listen(8020);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end place first

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {res.render('index')});
app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
  res.send("WHEEE");
});
```

second catch 404 and send to error handler

```js
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

and below handler error

```js
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

total code:

```js
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {res.render('index')});
app.get('/searching', function(req, res){
  res.send("WHEEE");
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
app.listen(8020);
```

Comment: Format your code more carefully. It will be clearer then.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Express FAQ](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html), you need to put your 404 handler at the very bottom, after all other functions have executed.

So just move your function down like so.

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);



app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index')
}); * * app.get('/searching', function(req, res) {
  res.send("WHEEE");
}); * *

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

module.exports = app;
app.listen(8020);
```